Prevent root items from being dropped onto another root item in PyQt5 QTreeView
I'm working on a PyQt5 application where I have a QTreeView populated with a QStandardItemModel. The root items present documents and the child sections within the document. So they should not be mixed. I want to achieve the following behaviors:

top level items can only be moved in a way that only their order changes, while still remaining in the top level
children can only be moved within the hierarchy of their top level parent

I've tried implementing custom dropEvent methods in my QTreeView subclass. I tried using dropEvent as the user can move the top level item order.
Here's a simplified version of my current implementation. The problem the code does allow the child to be moved outside of their top level item and the order of the top levels item can't be changed.
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTreeView, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel


class MyTreeView(QTreeView):

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        currentIndex = e.source().currentIndex()
        destinationIndex = self.indexAt(e.pos())

        # Check if the dragged item is a root item
        if not currentIndex.parent().isValid():
            # Check if the drop destination is a root item
            if not destinationIndex.parent().isValid():
                # Ignore the drop if both are root items
                e.ignore()
                return

        super().dropEvent(e)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tree_view = MyTreeView(self)
        self.tree_view.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.tree_view.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.tree_view.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        self.tree_view.setDragDropMode(QTreeView.InternalMove)

        self.model = QStandardItemModel()

        # Create sample items
        root_item1 = QStandardItem("Root Item 1")
        child_item11 = QStandardItem("Child Item 1.1")
        child_item12 = QStandardItem("Child Item 1.2")
        root_item1.appendRow(child_item11)
        root_item1.appendRow(child_item12)

        root_item2 = QStandardItem("Root Item 2")
        child_item21 = QStandardItem("Child Item 2.1")
        child_item22 = QStandardItem("Child Item 2.2")
        root_item2.appendRow(child_item21)
        root_item2.appendRow(child_item22)

        self.model.appendRow(root_item1)
        self.model.appendRow(root_item2)

        self.tree_view.setModel(self.model)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.tree_view)

        container = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


Your question is unclear. You first say that "a root item should not be droppable directly onto another root item", then you say that you've issues as "root items can't be moved freely over other root items", which is exactly what you wanted in the first phrase. Please try to clarify what you actually want to allow and prevent to the user. Also, consider that a more appropriate approach should allow or prevent dropping in dragMoveEvent(), so that it's also clear to the user if the action will be accepted or not before finding out when they've already dropped the item.

An abstract example isn't very helpful here, because it does not show what the full requirements are. For example, you do not say whether child items can move to the top-level, nor whether they can move between root items. The example code also currently allows root items to be dropped onto child items: is this as intended? It would be a lot easier to provide useful answers if your question explained what the role of this tree-view is within the context of your application.

Checking the target to decide if the drop may be accepted should not be done in the dropEvent(), because at that point the user has already dropped the item, and will find quite annoying to know that the action was not possible to begin with.
Such verification should always happen in the dragMoveEvent(), so that the user will immediately know if dropping will be possible and eventually decide to drag onto other targets.
Now, the complexity of the request demands that many possible combinations should be verified in order to eventually ignore the event (thus showing the user that dropping will have no effect).
Since the behavior changes depending on the dragged item and its level in the hierarchy (whether it's a top level item or not), it is better to define these aspects as soon as the drag begins.
This can be achieved by overriding startDrag() and do the preliminary checks before calling the default implementation, which actually begins the drag.
Then, in dragMoveEvent() we should first call the base implementation (which automatically excludes unacceptable drags), and from there ignore the event in case the drag event wasn't accepted to begin with or the drag wasn't started by the user (thus calling startDrag()).
If the condition above isn't matched, we continue by getting the current possible target of the drag movement, and by checking the current dropIndicatorPosition(): the indicator position is important to know the possible target of the drop, and can only be properly updated by the default dragMoveEvent() (thus making that call mandatory before doing anything else); the possible combinations are:

OnItem: the user is trying to drag on one item, possibly making the dragged item as a child of the target;
AboveItem: the user is near the top edge of one item, possibly making the dragged item as a sibling of the target (and inserted above);
BelowItem: the opposite, appending the item after the target;
OnViewport: the user is dragging on an empty area of the view, and dropping will eventually make the dragged item a new top level one, or it will cause reordering in case it already was;

Then, if the drag started from a top level item, we ignore the event if the the drop indicator position is not OnViewport (so, it's on an item) and:

if the target parent is valid (trying to drop on a child item);
or if the drop indicator position is OnItem (trying to drop on another top level item);

If the drag started from a child item instead, and the drop indicator is OnViewport, we're trying to drop a child as a top level item, so we ignore the event in this case.
If the above checks didn't already match an ignore or return condition, then we get the parent of the target.
If the parent of the target is not valid, the target is top level, so we may ignore the event if:

the drop indicator position is not OnItem (it may be above or below, causing the drop to become another top level sibling);
or if the "top parent" of the dragged item is different from the target;

Note that the second check above is because you may want to move a grand child to the top level parent.
Finally, if the parent of the target is valid, then go up in the hierarchy until we find its top level parent, and ignore the event if that top level parent is different from the top level parent of the dragged index.
class MyTreeView(QTreeView):
    dragIndex = dragTopParent = None
    def startDrag(self, actions):
        self.dragIndex = self.currentIndex()
        self.dragTopParent = self.dragIndex.parent()
        self.dragFromTopLevel = not self.dragTopParent.isValid()

        # get the top level parent in case it's not
        while self.dragTopParent.parent().isValid():
            self.dragTopParent = self.dragTopParent.parent()

        super().startDrag(actions)
        # at this point the drop has been completed, so we reset the 
        # attributes above for proper checking in dragMoveEvent
        self.dragIndex = self.dragTopParent = None

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        super().dragMoveEvent(event)
        # the event was already ignored, or wasn't caused by an internal move
        if not event.isAccepted() or self.dragIndex is None:
            return

        target = self.indexAt(event.pos())
        dropPos = self.dropIndicatorPosition()

        if self.dragFromTopLevel:
            # if dragging from a top level and dropping "between" items, we 
            # ignore the event if the target parent is valid (so it is not a 
            # top level) or we drop *on* an item
            if (
                dropPos != self.OnViewport
                and target.parent().isValid()
                or dropPos == self.OnItem
            ):
                event.ignore()
            return

        # if the drag index was not a top level...

        if dropPos == self.OnViewport:
            # dropping on the viewport would create a top level, ignore it
            event.ignore()
            return

        parent = target.parent()
        if not parent.isValid():
            # dropping on a top level, if dropping above/below or the top
            # level parent of the dragged index is different, we ignore it
            if dropPos != self.OnItem or self.dragTopParent != target:
                event.ignore()
            return

        # get the top level parent of the target
        while parent.parent().isValid():
            parent = parent.parent()

        if self.dragTopParent != parent:
            # if it's different than the top level parent of the drag, ignore
            event.ignore()

Note that there may be more ways to do the above checks, some of them more immediate in the execution (but also causing a code more difficult to read and debug). I decided for a more verbose implementation that explains the various checks done at each step.
Another solution is provided as a separate answer, which is based on a much simpler logic, but also requires proper object structure. This approach, instead, would work reliably with any given model used for the view.

Since the view only accepts a drag move (and drop) only based on the flags() the model returns, we can use a custom model (or a proxy) that eventually returns different flags depending on the situation.
This can be achieved by doing a "setup" on the model when the drag is about to begin, telling it which items may accept drops or not (including the root index, when dragging on the viewport), and eventually reverting to the default behavior when drag ends.
class CustomDragModel(QStandardItemModel):
    flagCheck = False
    dragFromTopLevel = False
    dragTopParent = None
    def dragAboutToBegin(self, dragIndex):
        self.flagCheck = True
        self.dragTopParent = dragIndex.parent()
        if not self.dragTopParent.isValid():
            self.dragFromTopLevel = True
        else:
            while self.dragTopParent.parent().isValid():
                self.dragTopParent = self.dragTopParent.parent()

    def dragEnded(self):
        self.flagCheck = False
        self.dragFromTopLevel = False
        self.dragTopParent = None

    def flags(self, index):
        if not self.flagCheck:
            return super().flags(index)
        flags = super().flags(index)

        if self.dragFromTopLevel:
            if index.isValid():
                flags &= ~Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled

        elif not index.isValid():
            flags &= ~Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled
        elif index != self.dragTopParent:
            parent = index.parent()
            while parent.parent().isValid():
                parent = parent.parent()
            if parent != self.dragTopParent:
                flags &= ~Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled

        return flags


class MyTreeView(QTreeView):
    def startDrag(self, actions):
        dragIndex = self.currentIndex()
        self.model().dragAboutToBegin(dragIndex)
        super().startDrag(actions)
        self.model().dragEnded()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ...
        self.model = CustomDragModel()
        ...

The benefit of this approach over the other solution I provided is that uses a much simpler logic that doesn't need too many steps to check if drop would be allowed or not, but it also makes it necessary to use two subclasses that are strictly related: the model of the view must implement the above functions.
This means that if you want to use proxy models for filtering/sorting, the above mechanism must be implemented in the "top level model".

Thanks, that's an elegant solution!

Do you mean the Root can not be as a sub-row inside another row ?
if that so, then you can disable dragging the root to any position :

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTreeView, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tree_view = QTreeView(self)

        self.tree_view.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.tree_view.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.tree_view.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        self.tree_view.setDragDropMode(QTreeView.InternalMove)

        self.model = QStandardItemModel()

        # Create sample items
        root_item1 = QStandardItem("Root Item 1")
        root_item1.setDragEnabled(False) # disable Draging the root

        child_item11 = QStandardItem("Child Item 1.1")
        child_item12 = QStandardItem("Child Item 1.2")
        root_item1.appendRow(child_item11)
        root_item1.appendRow(child_item12)



        root_item2 = QStandardItem("Root Item 2")
        root_item2.setDragEnabled(False)  # disable Draging the root
        child_item21 = QStandardItem("Child Item 2.1")
        child_item22 = QStandardItem("Child Item 2.2")
        root_item2.appendRow(child_item21)
        root_item2.appendRow(child_item22)



        self.model.insertRow(0,root_item1)
        self.model.insertRow(1, root_item2)


        self.tree_view.setModel(self.model)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.tree_view)

        container = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


try this.

The OP says that "Root items should be draggable and movable within the tree view hierarchy". Using setDragEnabled(False) prevents that.
